# How to center navigation within ul?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center the navigation at the top of this page:  http://www.escalatehosting.com/cloud-hosting.php

```
<div class="menu" style="text-align: center;">
<ul id="treemenu1" style="width:1000px;display: inline-block;margin: 0;padding: 0;zoom:1;*display: inline;">
<li><a href="http://www.escalatehosting.com/website-hosting.php" id="inactive">Website Hosting</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.escalatehosting.com/cloud-hosting.php" id="inactive">Cloud Hosting</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.escalatehosting.com/reseller-hosting.php" id="inactive">Reseller Hosting</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.escalatehosting.com/virtual-hosting.php" id="inactive">Virtual Servers</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.escalatehosting.com/dedicated-servers.php" id="inactive">Dedicated Servers</a>  </li>
<li><a href="http://www.escalatehosting.com/affiliate-program.php" id="inactive">Affiliate Program</a></li>
<li class="last">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Does anyone see what needs to be fixed?  I'm sure it's something stupid that I keep overlooking but can't seem to find it lol...

Comment: (not about centering...) You shouldn't have `id="inactive"` specified more than once. The DOM will just discard all but the first. You probably want `class="inactive"`.

Comment: inactive doesn't contain any styles, But `IDs` should be unique!

Comment: Is that what's causing the issue with center the entire UL?

Comment: @user2970202 No, it isn't!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `id="inactive"` to `class"inactive"` to make it semantically correct.
then, put all your styling in `css` rather than inline as inline will always over-write your external css

check this  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nDT3G/), you just need to take care of `#treemenu1`

**CSS**

```
.menu {
    width:98%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.menu > #treemenu1 {
    width:30%;
    text-align:left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.menu{
margin:0 auto;
width: 98%;
}
```

I think you want to center whole menu not the text of each menu as it is already centered.
Is it what you want? Hope this helps.

Comment: Just tried that and it didn't work, but what you're talking about is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: This will leave some space, all 3 things will not get aligned!

Comment: I think you have done something wrong in HTML markup of menu which creates some issue related to centering of menu. I am checking some and replying you back in few mins.